# Audio Loopback Dongle Sanity Check

Tags: analog, speakers, microphone

The same circuit as in [Explain “Audio Loopback Dongle"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486630/explain-audio-loopback-dongle); I wanted to know how it worked. Anything I couldn't figure out I found out via CircuitLab's time analysis:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwIkl9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is how I plan to use it. I want to know ahead of time if there are any problems. Will it smoke the phones?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSoXsl.png)</sup>

One thing I can't decide. Should the ground lines be connected?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK3oVq.png)</sup>

*Edit v1:* Changed the 0.1 uF capacitor to 1 uF because the 200 Hz signal was too filtered. Compensated by reducing the 100 Ohm resistors to 50 Ohm to keep the microphone signal between the standard 5-50 mV. Hope this makes sense.

*Edit v2:* Well it works. Only the grounded version above. I have no idea. Why? Answer this and I'll accept. I hope it doesn't switch the jack from CTIA to OMTP and bypass the entire circuit. Also the ground and mic lines on the left have to be shorted for a headphone to be detected.